# iOS: SDK iOS7 and XCode 4.6.3

Tags: ios, macos, sdk, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

My Mac has hardware problem for upgrading it to Mountain Lion (10.8) and now I have installed Lion (10.7). 
Is it possible for me to develop app for iOS7 with my Mac?

Comment: If you just look at the download page it tells you that you need Mountain Lion and at least 10.8.4. Right there on the download page. It would have been faster to have gone there and looked than to have typed the question.

Comment: @Abizern, the OP implies knowledge of this in the very qualifying statement preceding his question. Perhaps he was seeking a highly desired workaround, knowing that iOS 7 (& thus Xcode 5) officially requires OSX 10.8.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you wont be able to. XCode5 requires atleast Mountain Lion (10.8) to run. iOS7 SDK and the simulator is only available for XCode5.

Comment: I had the same problem with iOS 5 and Snow Leopard. At the time, a workaround was published here on StackOverflow, which allowed to use the iOS 5 SDK together with an older version of Xcode. The trick no longer worked with iOS 6, though. With iOS 7, there might be a similar way to use the SDK with the latest MacOS Lion version of Xcode. - But in any case, this would be an unsupported configuration, getting a new Mac including Mountain Lion is certainly the best way in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from Apple Developers:

> ... Xcode 5
>   Developer Preview requires OS X Mountain Lion or later.

I guess it will not be possible to run iOS7 SDK on Max OSX 10.7. I myself once had to buy a new Mac OSX in order to continue developing for the latest iOS.